# How to read Yes/No value as boolean from an Access database?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ms-access

Help me to retrieve the `YES/NO` Datatype from MS access in Boolean format.

I tried parsing it but it always returned false.

**UPDATE: Was not problem actually**
Sorry, it does accepts YES/NO as boolean values.

```
OleDbconnection dbConnect = new OleDbConnection(".....*.MDB");
dbConnect.Open();
.....
...
//xyz = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()
bool value = (bool)xyz[1];
```

Next time I'll research more and find minor mistakes before asking.. Sorry people

Comment: It is boolean and remains boolean.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried (your code more specifically)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the boolean of .Net is defined as

```
0 = false
1 = true
```

But MS Access uses the following values for its boolean

```
0 = false
-1 = true
```

So you have to manually convert this *integer values* to the corresponding boolean values.

Answer (score 2):

With the hope of finally putting this question to rest:

1. It **does not matter** what the Access Database Engine uses for its internal representations of `Yes/True` and `No/False`. We get back a `System.Boolean` value.
2. In Access, `Yes/No` fields are either `Yes/True` or `No/False`. `NULL` values are `No/False`.

Test data:

[image: YesNoTable.png]

Test code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace oleDbTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myConnectionString;
            myConnectionString =
                    @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                    @"Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;";

            using (var con = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                con.Open();

                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    // just to be sure, let's force one of the values to Null
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText =
                            "UPDATE YesNoTable SET YesNoField = NULL " +
                            "WHERE Description = 'Null'";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText =
                            "SELECT ID, YesNoField, Description FROM YesNoTable";
                    OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Row {0}:", rdr["ID"]));
                        bool boolValue = Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["YesNoField"]);
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("    Description is: {0}", rdr["Description"]));
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("    Return type is: {0}", rdr["YesNoField"].GetType()));
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("    raw value is: {0}", rdr["YesNoField"]));
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("    boolValue is: {0}", boolValue));
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Row 1:
    Description is: Yes
    Return type is: System.Boolean
    raw value is: True
    boolValue is: True

Row 2:
    Description is: No
    Return type is: System.Boolean
    raw value is: False
    boolValue is: False

Row 3:
    Description is: Null
    Return type is: System.Boolean
    raw value is: False
    boolValue is: False

Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
false = 0
true = !false
```

That's all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UseCurrInWords"].ToString()))
    chkBobUseCurrencyInWords.Checked = true;
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score -1):

From what I remember, the yes/no is actually a numeric of 1 or -1 where 1 is true.

Correction per Remou... 0 = false, -1 = true..  Last time I used Access was about 2005, so I wasn't perfect :)

Comment: @Remou, sorry about that... the last time I used access was back about 2005, but at least I remembered it wasn't something like "YES" or "NO"   as a string, or other  enumerable  :)

Answer (score -1):

ms access might be .mdb files or .accdb.

Watch with the debugger the values returned.

My guess is that true Is  == 0  and False is !=0.