# Checkbox has values of 0 and -1?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-1.1, asp.net-1.1

I have some checkboxes on my webapp, and a save button.  When I click the save button, I save the `checked` state of the checkboxes to the database.

When the checkboxes are not checked, I get `0`'s in the database.  However, when they are `checked`, I get `-1`'s in the database.  I was expecting `1`'s.  Are the `-1`'s normal for checked states?

**Sample code:**

```
Function ProcessAction(ByVal checkbox1 As Integer, ByVal checkbox2 As Integer) As Integer

    connection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("connString"))

    command = New SqlCommand("stored_procedure_name_here", connection)
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 4)).Value = 100
    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@checkbox1", SqlDbType.Int, 4)).Value = checkbox1
    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@checkbox2", SqlDbType.Int, 4)).Value = checkbox2

    command.Connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    command.Connection.Close()

    Return 1
End Function
```

**The call:**

```
Sub ButtonClick(ByVal Source As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)
    ProcessAction(checkbox1.Checked, checkbox2.Checked)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot will depend on the code in between, but a Boolean true value is conventionally represented as the integer value -1. It all depends on how you are handling the value before it gets persisted. Some code would be useful if you need further help.

---

EDIT: The code added shows you are relying on an implicit cast from Boolean to integer, resulting in this -1 value. In VB, depending on the version, you could use `Iif(checkbox1.Checked, 1, 0)` or `If(checkbox1.Checked, 1, 0)`. Alternatively, keep the value as a Boolean, and save to the appropriate underlying DBMS data type if there is one - for example, in SQL Server, this would be a `bit` data type.

Comment: You have already converted to int value -1 by the time you call this method ... show us the calling code...

Comment: So, you are implicitly casting a boolean (`checkbox1.Checked`) to an integer, resulting in the value `-1`. If you want any other value, you need to do this explicitly.

Comment: Is there a `proper` or `better` way to do this.  Sounds like I should really be saving the actual boolean values directly to the db instead of integers?

Comment: [SQL Server doesn't actually have a boolean data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx).  But you can use a BIT type (0, 1, or NULL).

Comment: Not exactly, no, it doesn't. But `bit` remains the appropriate underlying data type for a Boolean value for SQL Server. Didn't claim it was _actually_ a Boolean data type... ;)

Answer (score 1):

These would be true and false values in .NET, but the database may represent those values differently.  For instance, [Access uses -1 as a "true" value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940986/how-to-read-yes-no-value-as-boolean-from-ms-access)

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to use code like below

```
    Sql = CheckBoolean(Checkbox.checked)
Function CheckBoolean(Value As Boolean)
    If Value Then Return "-1"
    Return "0"
End Function
```